# Extracting data from xml into SQL server table

Tags: sql-server, xml, datatable, sql-function

My xml is in below format :

```
[My company customer detail - Account ID <3116131311616116>, Subscriber Name <Jon>, Age <52>, Phone <>, Payment<CC>]
```

I am unable to transfer data from xml to SQL server table columns. columns name like Account ID, Subscriber Name, Age , Phone ,Payment

[image]

Detail of xml mentions above seems like string. XML(String) is in column like below :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8QyI.png)

I need to extract data from detail column and push data into new table with attributes from xml/string.

Comment: That doesn't look like XML to me. What have you tried so far? How is your XML provided (flat file, data you can query from another database)? Does it always have the same format? How much XML are you processing?

Comment: That is definitely *not* XML data. I don't know what it is meant to be, but I would suggest that whatever consumes it into a dataset is *not* SQL Server. Whatever language you use, it needs to be one with good string manipulation and preferably REGEX support; SQL Server offers neither of those.

Comment: What is the SQL Server version?

Comment: Detail is in table in form of columns, required xml mentions above seems to me more string than xml.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a super-duper hack that's not limited to a set number of "columns":

```
-- Data mock-up.
DECLARE @value VARCHAR(500) = '[My company customer detail - Account ID <3116131311616116>, Subscriber Name <Jon>, Age <52>, Phone <>, Payment<CC>]';

-- Construct the dynamic SQL field/value list.
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @sql = ISNULL( @sql, '' ) 
    + ', ' + QUOTENAME( SUBSTRING( value, CHARINDEX( '<', value ) + 1, CHARINDEX( '>', value ) - CHARINDEX( '<', value ) - 1 ), '''' )
    + ' AS [' + LTRIM( RTRIM( LEFT( value, CHARINDEX( '<', value ) - 1 ) ) ) + ']'
FROM STRING_SPLIT( REPLACE( REPLACE( @value, ']', '' ), '[', '' ), ',' )

-- Complete the dynamic SQL.
SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + STUFF( @sql, 1, 2, '' ) + ';';

-- Print the resulting dynamic SQL.
PRINT @sql;

-- Execute the dynamic SQL.
EXEC( @sql );
```

PRINT displays:

```
SELECT '3116131311616116' AS [My company customer detail - Account ID], 'Jon' AS [Subscriber Name], '52' AS [Age], '' AS [Phone], 'CC' AS [Payment];
```

EXEC returns:

```
+-----------------------------------------+-----------------+-----+-------+---------+
| My company customer detail - Account ID | Subscriber Name | Age | Phone | Payment |
+-----------------------------------------+-----------------+-----+-------+---------+
|                        3116131311616116 | Jon             |  52 |       | CC      |
+-----------------------------------------+-----------------+-----+-------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

By "transfer data from xml to SQL server table columns" I am assuming you mean insert to sql server table. if so this means that parsing the xml is done at the application and you should then construct a string in the form of insert..values, but surly more information is needed.
Another option can be to pass the xml as an input parameter to the stored procedure, parse the xml within the procedure and insert the table.
The more info you provide will help to answer your issue better.
The 2 options are valid and this is a matter of design and preference. In general if the xml you are dealing with is large then doing the parsing at the application is preferred.

Comment: Hi Yaniv, Detail seems to me more like string. I am extracting detail from table column which seems to be xml but not in xml format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use such a query

```
SELECT CAST([XMLData] AS XML).value('(/MyCompany/AccountID)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS "Account ID",
       CAST([XMLData] AS XML).value('(/MyCompany/SubscriberName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS "Subscriber Name",
       CAST([XMLData] AS XML).value('(/MyCompany/Age)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS "Age",
       CAST([XMLData] AS XML).value('(/MyCompany/Phone)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS "Phone",
       CAST([XMLData] AS XML).value('(/MyCompany/Payment)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS "Payment"
  FROM tab
```

assuming you have a column `[XMLData]` within the table of type `VARCHAR` with the value

```
<MyCompany>
  <AccountID>3116131311616116</AccountID>
  <Phone></Phone>
  <Age>52</Age>
  <SubscriberName>Jon</SubscriberName>
  <Payment>CC</Payment>
</MyCompany>
```

depending of the provided data.

If the column is of type `XML`, then casting is not needed, e.g. use as `[XMLData].value`

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e3c10dec53b87d8b47e0711aa2203926)</kbd>

Comment: Hi Barbaros, thanks for helping. My detail data is not in xml format, its more in string. I need to extract attributes and push the data into table.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

First, garbled string is converted to XML. The moment it is XML the rest is trivial.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @unstructured VARCHAR(max) = '[My company customer detail - Account ID <3116131311616116>, Subscriber Name <Jon>, Age <52>, Phone <>, Payment<CC>]';

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = '>'
    , @lt CHAR(1) = '<';

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
                REPLACE(@unstructured, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
               ']]></r></root>' AS XML) AS xmldata
), cte AS
(
    SELECT c.value('(r[1]/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS col1
        , c.value('(r[2]/text())[1]','VARCHAR(30)') AS col2
        , c.value('(r[3]/text())[1]','VARCHAR(30)') AS col3
        , c.value('(r[4]/text())[1]','VARCHAR(30)') AS col4
        , c.value('(r[5]/text())[1]','VARCHAR(30)') AS col5
    FROM rs CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/root') AS t(c)
)
SELECT STUFF(col1, 1, CHARINDEX(@lt, col1,1), '') AS AccountID
    , STUFF(col2, 1, CHARINDEX(@lt, col2,1), '') AS SubscriberName
    , STUFF(col3, 1, CHARINDEX(@lt, col3,1), '') AS Age
    , STUFF(col4, 1, CHARINDEX(@lt, col4,1), '') AS Phone
    , STUFF(col5, 1, CHARINDEX(@lt, col5,1), '') AS Payment
FROM cte;
```

**Output**

```
+------------------+----------------+-----+-------+---------+
|    AccountID     | SubscriberName | Age | Phone | Payment |
+------------------+----------------+-----+-------+---------+
| 3116131311616116 | Jon            |  52 |       | CC      |
+------------------+----------------+-----+-------+---------+
```